# sudo apt-update fails to fetch 2 packages on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

The two offending packages:

```
E:Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-ppc64el/Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 103.97.84.254 80], 
E:Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/binary-ppc64el/Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 103.97.84.254 80], 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My sources.lists file contents- https://pastebin.com/50PpLG3y

I am able to upgrade but not update.

Already tried `rf rf lists/*` and apt update, didn't work.
Trying to update from update manager gives check internet connection error

Comment: Are you using PowerPC?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by powerpc. I am using an intel i5 9th gen Lenovo Legion

Comment: What is the output of `uname -m` and  `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`?

Comment: uname -m gives x86_64

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures gives 
i386
ppc64el

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture ppc64el` and then `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Also I have a NVIDIA GeForce 1660T installed with Driver version 440.82, I don't know if this is relevant or not

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce 1660T is a GPU not a CPU. You don't really need ppc64el architecture.

Comment: Hey it worked. Could you please tell me what ppc64el architecture does, and possible reasons it could have installed automatically? I tried to read the documentation page but I didn't understand too much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [amd64 vs ppc64el](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808166/amd64-vs-ppc64el) and https://askubuntu.com/q/267954

Comment: Kind of, no idea how it came up as a problem after so long, been using the system for 6 months now. Anyway, thank you for the answer, could you post it as an answer instead of comment so that I could upvote you and mark the question as solved?

Comment: Well the issue was because of foreign architecture being added. I think https://askubuntu.com/q/267954 answers your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove a foreign architecture?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267954/how-to-remove-a-foreign-architecture)